# Need help soccer simulation

Tags: c++, simulation

I need help with a winning condition and randomly placing teams against each other...i randomly selecting teams to play and i keep getting the same teams playing twice or playing itself and idk what to do

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>


using namespace std;

        struct teams{//declaring a struct for the teams
        string side;
        int number;
        int number1;

    }teams1[16], points[16];

//void intro screen(){//function for the introduction screen

void fileData(){//function for reading the teams data file

    ifstream input;
    input.open("FootballTeam.txt",ios::in); //associate file

    if(input.is_open()){//opening the file

        for(int x=0; x<16; x++){//looping through the file

                input>>teams1[x].side;//getting info from the file
                cout<<teams1[x].side<<endl;//printing out the data from the file

        }//end for
    }//end if
}//end void

void play(){//function for playing the game
srand(time(NULL));
    for(int x=0; x<=1; x++){//loop for random teams to play
            for(int s=0; s<=7; s++){//loop for randoms goals value

        x=rand() %16+1;//randomly selecting two teams
        points[s].number=rand()%4+1;//randomly selecting goals
        points[s].number1=rand()%7+3;//randomly selecting goals
        cout<<teams1[x].side<<" :"<<points[s].number<<" vs "
        <<teams1[s].side<<" :"<<points[s].number1<<endl<<endl;//printing out the teams and goals

        //cout<<teams1<<" Won this match"<<endl;
        }//end for
    }//end for
}//end void
int main (){
cout<<"ROUND OF 16 Finalists!!!\n"<<endl;
fileData();
cout<<"\n";
system("PAUSE");
system("CLS");

play();
return 0;
}//end main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rand()` pseudo-random number generator uses its default seed if you don't call `srand()` before using `rand()`. To prevent `rand()` from using the default seed on every run of your program, and thereby always choosing the same pairs of teams, you should call `srand()` and pass in `time(NULL)`, which I see you have done. Since your program will never run at the same time twice, `rand()` will output different numbers on each run.

However, note that you should only call `srand()` once. **So you need to call it in `main()`, as soon as your program starts up.** Right now you're calling `srand()` every time `play()` is invoked. The time intervals between each invocation of `play()` are probably very small. Thus, `rand()` ends up being seeded with virtually the same number every time, since the time differences are too small. This effectively starts `rand()` at the same point in its pseudo-random number sequence, which is why you see the same teams playing each other.

```
int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    // now you're free to use rand() for the rest of the program
    // ...
}
```

See [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/) for more information on `srand()`.